# SQL Server 2012: Can an IIF Function pick up the last assigned value based on a condition

Tags: sql-server, iif-function

Let's say I have a table that looks like this:

```
+---------+-----------+------------+
| Company |  Quantity |     Date   |
+---------+-----------+------------+
| A       |     10000 | 2016-08-01 |
| B       |     -5000 | 2016-08-01 |
| C       |      5000 | 2016-08-01 |
| A       |      5000 | 2016-08-02 |
| B       |     -2500 | 2016-08-02 |
| C       |      5000 | 2016-08-02 |
| A       |         0 | 2016-08-03 |
| B       |         0 | 2016-08-03 |
| C       |      5000 | 2016-08-03 |
+---------+-----------+------------+
```

I am trying to create a view with a column called IssuerLS where if the quantity is +ve, the column value will be 'L' and if the quantity is -ve, the column value will be 'S'. That part is easy with the IIF function but I also want to use the last known value if the Quantity is 0. So my view should look like this:

```
+---------+----------+------------+----------+
| Company | Quantity |    Date    | IssuerLS |
+---------+----------+------------+----------+
| A       |    10000 | 2016-08-01 | L        |
| B       |    -5000 | 2016-08-01 | S        |
| C       |     5000 | 2016-08-01 | L        |
| A       |     5000 | 2016-08-02 | L        |
| B       |    -2500 | 2016-08-02 | S        |
| C       |     5000 | 2016-08-02 | L        |
| A       |        0 | 2016-08-03 | L        |
| B       |        0 | 2016-08-03 | S        |
| C       |     5000 | 2016-08-03 | L        |
+---------+----------+------------+----------+
```

Is there a way to do get the IIF Function to use the last known 'L' or 'S' value for each Company if the Quantity is 0?

Thanks.

Comment: iif() only sees the values of its inputs. `iif(somecondition, truevalue, falsevalue)`. YOU have to supply the logic for `somecondition`, not iif().

Comment: what is the logic for adding L and S based on last known value

Comment: So for e.g with Company A, If Quantity =0, then go back to the last known date where the quantity isn't 0 (in this case 2016-08-02) and add "L" or "S" depending on the quantity on that date (in this case, "L").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ;with cte
    as
    (select *,
    case 
    when qty>0 then 'l' 
    when qty<0 then 'S' 
    else null end as newval
     from #tmp
     )
     select c1.cmp,c1.qty,c1.date,
     case when newval is null then rplcval else newval end as somecol
      from cte  c1
     cross apply
     (
     select top 1 newval as rplcval from cte c2 where c2.date<=c1.date and c1.cmp = c2.cmp
order by date) b
```

Answer (score 1):

can be done using case and outer apply.

```
SELECT  *,
        CASE WHEN Quantity = 0 THEN CASE WHEN prevQuantity > 0 THEN 'L' ELSE 'S'END
             ELSE CASE WHEN Quantity > 0 THEN 'L' ELSE 'S' END
        END
FROM    Table1 t1
        OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
                            Quantity prevQuantity
                     FROM   Table1 t2
                     WHERE  t2.Company = t1.Company
                            AND t2.Date < t1.Date
                            AND t2.Quantity <> 0
                     ORDER BY [Date] DESC
                    ) t2
```

if you want to use IIF then

```
SELECT  *,
        IIF(Quantity <> 0, IIF(Quantity > 0, 'L','S'), IIF(prevQuantity > 0, 'L','S'))
FROM    Table1 t1
        CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1
                            Quantity prevQuantity
                     FROM   Table1 t2
                     WHERE  t2.Company = t1.Company
                            AND t2.Date <= t1.Date
                            AND t2.Quantity <> 0
                     ORDER BY [Date] DESC
                    ) t2
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried both and they both worked. I'll have to read up on OUTER APPLY and CROSS APPLY as I'm not familiar with them.